# Any way to send metrics to Confluent Control Center from any Java application (not using Kafka Consumer or Producer)

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

We have an application making HTTP calls to KafkaRestProxy. How can I include this application in the Data Stream Monitoring system provided in Confluent Control Center. Currently, the only way I saw to send metrics to Confluent Control Center is adding monitoring-interceptors to producer or consumer. But is there any client to sent it?

Comment: So you can't make the REST Proxy add those interceptors?

Comment: Maybe you can, but then your monitor system still does not include the application that's making the HTTP calls, right?

Comment: Doubtful, but you could include that as part of the Kafka message/key/header, no?